# c++ using bool in a class with set and get functions

Tags: c++, oop, boolean

I am trying to create a class with private attributes and change values with set and get functions. However i cant seem to change the bool value

```
class VideoGames {
    private:    
    bool buy;
    
    public: 
    bool get_buy(){return buy;} 
    void set_buy(bool b){b = buy;}
};
```

```
main(){
VideoGames g1;
double price;
cin >> price;
if(price <=100){
        g1.set_buy(true);
    }
else {
        g1.set_buy(false);
}
cout<<"Buy= " << g1.get_buy()<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

this always prints out 0 no matter what the price is. What do i need to change?

Comment: This looks like a simple typo: `void set_buy(bool b){b = buy;}`, it should be `void set_buy(bool b){buy = b;}`

Comment: Oh God, who gives you the idea that incapsulation would work this way? Having a private member and getter and setter function is not incapsulation but profanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You flip-flopped the assignment; `b = buy;` reassigns the parameter (which is then thrown away so nothing changes), you wanted `buy = b;` to reassign the attribute *from* the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

when using the "=" sign, the right side gets put in the left side, so instead of:

```
void set_buy(bool b){b = buy;}
```

write:

```
void set_buy(bool b){buy = b;}
```